# Where and how to import custom Object prototype properties file which is required globally in gatsby during develop & build step?

Tags: typescript, gatsby

**CONTEXT :**

- I have a typescript file which contains CUSTOM OBJECT PROTOTYPE functions / properties.
- This file ( `utils.ts` ) should be available globally when the app starts and should extend the existing Object prototype.
- Importing this file `gatsby-browser.js` is working in `gatsby develop` mode.
- When building / deploying this fails.

**QUESTION :**

- How and where should i import these kind of files in gatsby, so that it's available during build phase globally ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the error output when fails?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I have added new screenshots. During build step the custom array function "random" is not recognized. Now the question is where should i import this utility file for both develop and build step globally ?